# (Numerical Analysis) What is the largest double float represented for the gamma function and $n!$

Tags: floating-point, numerical-analysis

Consider that
\begin{align}
 \Gamma(n+1) = n!
\end{align}
for any integers. I then got the following two questions:

1. What is the largest value of $n$ for which $Γ(n+1)$ and $n!$ can be exactly represented by a double-precision floating-point number?
2. What is the largest value of $n$ for which $Γ(n+1)$ and $n!$ can be approximately represented by a double-precision floating-point number that does not overflow?

So I have been working on this question for some time now but I do not seem to be satisfied by my own answer.
My thoughts so far on (1.) is that since we start getting non representable integers after $2^{53}$ my initial guess would be the largest $n$ such that $n!=\Gamma(n+1)<2^{53}$. I found this value to be $n=18$ through MatLab simulations, I do wonder though if there are still some precisely represented for $n>18$, and how would I go about testing that?

I have run $\Gamma(n+1) - n!$ for several $n>18$ and they start getting some serious errors but only after $n=22$. It makes intuitive sense to me that the gamma function should produce more errors as it is a an approximation of an integral, but how am I to know that $23!$ is not also represented?

I also considered finding zeros for
$$0=n! - (1+f)\cdot2^e$$
w.r.t $f$, note that $(1+f)$ is the mantissa and $2^e$ is the radix, such that the second term is in fact the positive normalized representation of the double float. My thought is that it would only be able to find a zero in case $f$ was a representable as a double float, however, I figured that this could not be done like this as $n!$ would always be either true or a rounding to a double float, so in any case MatLab would always be able to find a representable $f$ that produced a zero.

I am not sure how to continue with this exercise, any good pointers?

Comment: The Gamma function is not evaluated by numerical integration. In fact, the accuracy might be better for larger values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice one. Using the standard ieee 754 double precision floating point format, we can exactly represent integers less than $2^{53}$, multiplied by a power of 2. When we try to find the largest n where n! can be represented that way, then for example the factor 12 of 12! equals $3 \cdot 2^2$. If my calculator gets it right then the largest n is 22, with $22! ≈ 1.124 \cdot 10^{21}$; 22! has the factor $2^{19}$, and $22! / 2^{19} < 2^{51}$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the table below, showing naturals and the binary representation of their factorial with trailing bits stripped off.

IEEE single/double/quadruple precision are able to represent $13!$/$22!/37!$ exactly.

$$\begin{array}
&0! & 1 & 1 \\
1! & 1 & 1 \\
2! & 1 & 1 \\
3! & 2 & 11 \\
4! & 2 & 11 \\
5! & 4 & 1111 \\
6! & 6 & 101101 \\
7! & 9 & 100111011 \\
8! & 9 & 100111011 \\
9! & 12 & 101100010011 \\
10! & 14 & 11011101011111 \\
11! & 18 & 100110000100010101 \\
12! & 19 & 1110010001100111111 \\
13! & 23 & 10111001100101000110011 \\
14! & 26 & 10100010011000011101100101 \\
15! & 30 & 100110000011101110111011101011 \\
16! & 30 & 100110000011101110111011101011 \\
17! & 34 & 1010000110111111011101110110011011 \\
18! & 37 & 1011010111110111011001100101001110011 \\
19! & 41 & 11011000000101011100100110000011010001001 \\
20! & 44 & 10000111000011011001110111110010000010101101 \\
21! & 48 & 101100010100000111011111010011011010111000110001 \\
22! & 51 & 111100111011101010010011000010101100111110000011011 \\
23! & 56 & 10101111001011100001100110101111110001010010011001101101 \\
24! & 58 & 1000001101100010100100110100001111010011110111001101000111\\ \cdots\end{array}$$

---

Regarding the non-overflowing value, it suffices to accumulate the base-2 logarithms of the naturals until you reach $128/1024/16384$. This can be done by brute-force. We have

$$\begin{array}
&\log_234! \sim 127.79512061296911\\
\log_2170! \sim 1019.3694529277266\\
\log_21754! \sim 16378.090470312889\\
\end{array}$$ and larger values will overflow.

---

My old TI SR-56 supported factorials up to $69!$ (overflow at $10^{100}$).